# How does compiler infer the delegate type from LAMBDA expression?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, lambda

### SAMPLE CODE

```
int id = 123;

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => ThreadEntryPoint((int)state), id);

public void ThreadEntryPoint(int uniqueId)
{
   Console.WriteLine("uniqueId=" + uniqueId);
}
```

### QUESTION

From the provided LAMBDA expression, how does the compiler know that it needs to create an instance of `QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback, Object)`?

More specifically: I understand that it is inferring the delegate type.  What I don't understand is what decision tree (from a high level) is it going through to select the correct delegate type to instantiate?

### REFERENCES

- [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem(v=vs.110).aspx)

  - `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback, Object)`
- [WaitCallback Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback(v=vs.110).aspx)

  - `QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback, Object)`
  - `QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback)`

Comment: Actually the compiler doesn't create any instances not would it create an instance of `QueueUserWorkItem` because that is a method. But the method `QueueUserWorkItem` expects an `WaitCallback` delegate and the delegate itself is specified as having no return type (`void`) and taking one argument (`object`) like this `public delegate void WaitCallback(Object state);`. Your written lambda statement represents an anonymous method. So this anonymous method will be "encapsulated" within an `WaitCallback` delegate (added into the invocation list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does compiler infer the delegate type from LAMBDA expression?

Fundamentally, it doesn't.

The compiler infers the delegate type from the available overloads in the method group named `QueueUserWorkItem`. There are only two overloads, and only one with two parameters, and both overloads use the delegate type `WaitCallback`.

Thus, the delegate type *has* to be `WaitCallback`. With this determined, the compiler can then compile the lambda expression as an anonymous method and instantiate as the parameter to the `QueueUserWorkItem()` method call the necessary delegate object to call that anonymous method.

In a more complicated scenario, the compiler would have to perform some analysis to determine the "best" match for the overload, and that analysis may involve the lambda expression to the extent that it can eliminate overload possibilities based on the lambda expression.

But at no point does the compiler start with the lambda expression and go directly to the delegate type. For a lambda expression to be converted to a delegate instance, there needs to be some other context for the lambda expression that determines the needed delegate type, such as assignment to a typed variable, an explicit cast, or (as in this case) a method overload where the parameter the lambda expression is used for has a specific delegate type compatible with the lambda expression.

Note that there is still type inference for generic methods, in which the lambda is used to infer type parameters. [Eric Lippert's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163285/how-does-compiler-infer-the-delegate-type-from-lambda-expression/38163788?noredirect=1#comment63799674_38163788) explains this clearly:

> There are some instances where the compiler must infer the constructed delegate type from the lambda. For example, if we have `M<A, R>(Func<A, R> f)` and `M((string x) => x.Length)` then the compiler will infer `Func<string, something>` first, from the lambda parameter, and then `Func<string, int>` from the body of the lambda.

My point here is that the compiler won't infer `Func<T, TResult>` from scratch. As Eric points out, the compiler does use the lambda to infer the type parameters, but the compiler still requires context in which the open generic type is known.

For more details, you should read [the C# specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31617711/where-can-i-find-the-c-sharp-language-specification-6-0). It will detail how the overload resolution is performed and the rules that govern that and matching lambda expressions to types.

Additional reading:
[.Net lambda expression— where did this parameter come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8330446)
[Why can't an anonymous method be assigned to var?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4965576)
[Why can't the compiler tell the better conversion target in this overload resolution case? (covariance)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20398705)
[Convert this delegate to an anonymous method or lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59515)
Not coincidentally, the first three include excellent discussions of the topic and related issues written by Eric Lippert, who used to work on the Visual Studio C# compiler and language design teams.

Comment: Always of interest to me is the "stop point" at which the compiler says "i cant infer a better match so i must fail," common in situations where no implicit cast exist but an explicit one does.

Comment: There are two different issues there. First is overload resolution, the second is type inference for generic methods. But yes, there are situations where the context does not constrain the available method overloads sufficiently for the compiler to make a determination. The C# specification details the overload resolution and type inference rules, culminating in an error if following the rules in the specification does not result in a unique outcome.

Comment: @Peter: Thank you for providing some insight into how this works!

Comment: There are some instances where the compiler must infer the *constructed* delegate type from the lambda. For example, if we have `M<A, R>(Func<A, R> f)` and `M((string x) => x.Length)` then the compiler will infer `Func<string, something>` first, from the lambda parameter, and then `Func<string, int>` from the body of the lambda. But in no case does the compiler infer the `Func` type from the lambda, which is what I think what you were getting at in this answer.

Comment: @EricLippert: _"which is what I think what you were getting at in this answer"_ -- yes, that's correct. Thanks very much for the additional clarification. I will add that to the answer.